# Android Studio does not steps into virtual functions during debug

Tags: c++, android-studio, debugging, android-ndk

I am debugging an Android application with lots of C++ code (built with gradle, using NDK). However i ahve run into a nearly-fatal issue.

When there is a pointer (or smart pointer) to some some object of base, possibly pure virtual class, debugger does not show me what the real class is. Likewise, when i try to "Step into" the virtual function being called, debugger steps over instead. If there is a breakpoint inside, it will stop there, though.

How can i retrieve that information in runtime when debugging? I can somewhat change the build if needed.

Here is a code sample for what i am trying to debug

```
  bool Result = false;

  const size_t HandlersCount = m_Handlers.size();
  for (size_t i = 0; i < HandlersCount; ++i)
  {
    const auto Handler = m_Handlers[i];
    if (Handler.IsNotNULL() &&
        Handler->HandleInputEvent(_Event))
    {
      Result = true;
      break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: please show us some code to help you

Comment: added some code. Hope that would help, but do not see how